# How to make the display go to sleep mode when Lion's Terminal.app is in full-screen mode?

Tags: terminal, screensaver

I've noticed that when I'm running a full-screen Terminal.app in Lion, the display does not go to sleep.  This left me with a nasty case of burn-in over the weekend with a magenta message box from an Ubuntu upgrade.

I want screensaver and sleep to behave normally even when my Terminal is in full-screen mode.

Is there a way to override this behavior?

Comment: Can you be more specific, we're you on an Ubuntu machine or a Apple computer? Which Apple computer? What version of OSX?

Comment: This is Terminal.app on OSX Lion (connected to an Ubuntu machine over SSH)

Comment: Are you sure it was Terminal keeping the machine awake? Terminal doesn’t do anything to explicitly disable the screensaver or sleep. I suppose it’s possible that the network connection may be keeping the computer awake, but I wouldn’t expect it to prevent display sleep. It sounds like something else is the issue—possibly whatever program(s) you’re running via the Terminal.